# If you're binding to an object with read-only properties, should you still implement INotifyPropertyChanged?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, binding, poco, inotifypropertychanged

While writing the API for some components we're developing,  we have a need to expose some read-only POCO objects which the user can (and most likely will) create data templates for in their app, thus they will be using bindings to them.

Now I know that you can bind to straight POCO objects (i.e. not subclassed of `DependencyObject`) even if they don't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` but when you do, unless you explicitly mark those bindings as one-time, you're creating unnecessary references to your objects and potentially exposing memory leaks.

Excerpt from [this article](https://adityaswami89.wordpress.com/2014/08/07/wpf-binding-with-pocos-works):

> [...] This has 2 implications, this action causes the common language runtime (CLR) to create a strong reference from this PropertyDescriptor object to object X. The CLR also keeps a reference to the PropertyDescriptor object in a global table.

Now while we can try and document that all bindings to these objects should be one-time, that puts the burden on the consumer.  I'm wondering if it makes sense to just implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` anyway, even though nothing ever changes specifically to defensively address the memory leaks.

*In other words, which is heavier, binding to a POCO property without using one-time, or implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` defensively?*

Is there any down-side to doing so? While not as lightweight as one-time bindings, it still has to be better than the effect caused by a consumer *not* setting them to one-time.

If it makes any difference, there will only be a hundred or so of these so a very small set.

Comment: I appreciate that they might not be as elegant but you might want to consider implementing read-only dependency properties. That way there would be no need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`

Comment: What would be the benefit of implementing INotifyPropertyChanged and then never fire its PropertyChanged event? The CLR would *still* create and keep a reference to the PropertyDescriptor. So the answer to your question is clearly: "No, you shouldn't".

Comment: @Bijington, you can't implement Dependency Properties on a POCO. It would have to be a subclass of `DependencyObject`, and if it were, this question wouldn't apply.

Comment: @Clemens, yes, there's still a reference, but it's a *much* smaller cost than for an object that doesn't implement the interface, hence my question.

Comment: I don't get it, with or without INPC, a reference would be kept. Where is the benefit then?

Comment: It's not about the reference. It's about the weight of how it's referenced.  If you google around bindings of POCOs (i.e. not subclasses of `DependencyObject`s and which also don't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`), you'll see it can introduce memory leaks, etc. if you don't set the bindings as one-time.  My question is, to avoid those potential leaks (to make it easier on consumers of my API), if it makes sense to implement the interface (which again, still holds a reference, just much lighter weight) even though nothing will ever change.  Make sense?

Comment: @MarqueIV very good point! I am not entirely sure how I missed POCO from your question. If it is an API for use should you even be worrying about implementing INotifyPropertyChanged. Ultimately if they are using it for bindings then that is their consideration to make. You can’t expect to cover all cases with your classes and shouldn’t expect to.

Comment: Yeah, but if the cost is minimal, why not help where I can?  That's what I'm wondering.  But yes, ultimately it should be on the consumer of the API to do things correctly, i.e. one-time bindings.

Comment: Makes no sense at all. The potential memory leaks caused by Bindings are also there when you implement INPC. It doesn't change anything. And instead of asking us to "google around" why not just provide some reference? Any *evidence* why implementing INPC would avoid a memory leak?

Comment: Sorry, but it does make sense. It's well-known in the WPF community. You're the one stating the contrary. But if you want evidence from my end, here's a link from Microsoft themselves that a simple search 'wpf binding to non-INPC objects causes leak' brings right up: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/micmcd/2008/03/07/avoiding-a-wpf-memory-leak-with-databinding-black-magic.

Comment: ...and actually, from that same article, I noticed a blurb at the end stating "Anything involved in a data-binding should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. You don't have to raise the `PropertyChanged` event if you don't particularly feel like it, but to avoid the leak you have to implement the interface." so I guess that validates I was on the right track and can mark the other person's answer as the correct one. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any down-side to doing so?

The downside if any should be negligible. There is obviously a very minor memory penalty. Besides that you need to define the `PropertyChanged` event in your POCO class, WPF will also subscribe to it and this will allocate an extra 4 or 8 bytes depending on your CPU architecture. But this is not really a valid reason no to implement the interface.

So if you are concerned about memory leaks and know for a fact that not all bindings to your class' properties will be defined as `OneTime`, it does no harm to implement the interface as a guard for this. You may want to leave a comment in the code that mentions why the interface is implemented despite the event never being raised.

Comment: You can never know for sure what consumers of your API will do! :) #DefensiveProgramming

Comment: Actually, thanks to the snarky comments of someone else on here, I grabbed a blog post from Microsoft showing there is in fact a memory leak when binding to non-INPC POCOs (he was incorrectly stating there wasn't), and it specifically says "Anything involved in a databinding should implement INotifyPropertyChanged.  You don't have to raise the PropertyChanged event if you don't particularly feel like it, but to avoid the leak you have to implement the interface." so there you go! :) https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/micmcd/2008/03/07/avoiding-a-wpf-memory-leak-with-databinding-black-magic

Comment: Well, instead of blindly believing what someone wrote in a blog post in 2008, I'd suggest to write a small test program to see if the problem is still present. I did, and I am unable to observe even the tiniest memory leak while constantly creating and removing Bindings to a view model property in a class that does not implement INotifyPropertyChanged (with .NET 4.7.2 on Windows 10). I did not read all WPF release notes of the past ten years, but probably they just fixed it. After all, while it doesn't hurt much, implementing INPC without reason seems pointless, at least nowadays.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should definitely implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for any POCO that might be used with **WPF** data binding, even if the object's properties never change.

As always with `INotifyPropertyChanged` (and also in this case), there is no need to fire the event for the initial values which are set in the constructor. This is because, at the time of executing the constructor, there is (normally <sup>[1.]</sup> ) no possibility of the event having any subscribers yet.

Finally (since it hasn't been mentioned yet on this page), you can ***avoid the memory waste*** penalty in this situation by using a vacuous version of the manual event implementation syntax in **C#**, without declaring any event delegate. Both the explicit and public interface implementation modes are supported, you can choose whichever is your preference:

**1. Vacuous event implementation (explicit)**

```
public class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int InvariantProperty => 42;

    event PropertyChangedEventHandler INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
    {
        add { }
        remove { }
    }
}
```

**2. Vacuous event implementation (public)**

```
public class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int InvariantProperty => 42;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged
    {
        add { }
        remove { }
    }
}
```

Notice that there's no `EventHandler` delegate declared in the examples, but the important thing is the class still advertizes (inherently moribund) "notifications." Doing so trivially satisfies the **WPF** binding engine, and thus prevents it from deploying its more invasive and expensive tactics.

<sup>1. Of course the unwise bad-practice alluded to here would be calling virtual methods from your constructor--or directly calling into external code--prior to the constructor being finished.</sup>